# why java does not support multiple inheritance

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there is no multiple inheritance in Java, but implementing multiple interfaces is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515477/why-there-is-no-multiple-inheritance-in-java-but-implementing-multiple-interface)

hi all, I am new to java and when I am try to use multiple inheritance concept in java its showing a compile time error.Why java does not support it.I heard about interface key word but 
do not know why java support it directly. please help me in this and explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515477/why-there-is-no-multiple-inheritance-in-java-but-implementing-multiple-interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008683/why-does-java-allow-multiple-inheritance-from-interfaces-but-not-from-abstract-co http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262447/multiple-inheritance-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038314/alternative-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple inheritance can be really difficult to understand. When you have a multiple inheritance with two classes which have methods in conflicts, how do you handle this ?

Of course solutions exist (in C++ for example) but the creators of Java decided it was way to complicated and not really in the Java philosophy (make development a lot easier).

From sun.com :

> Multiple inheritance--and all the problems it generates--was discarded from Java. The desirable features of multiple inheritance are provided by interfaces--conceptually similar to Objective C protocols.
>   An interface is not a definition of a class. Rather, it's a definition of a set of methods that one or more classes will implement. An important issue of interfaces is that they declare only methods and constants. Variables may not be defined in interfaces.

---

**Resources :**

- [The Java Language Environment](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Simple.doc2.html)

Answer (score 21):

The main problem with multiple inheritance (alluded to by Colin and Rin) is known is [The Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).

I quote:

> The diamond problem is an ambiguity
>   that arises when two classes B and C
>   inherit from A, and class D inherits
>   from both B and C. If a method in D
>   calls a method defined in A (and does
>   not override the method), and B and C
>   have overridden that method
>   differently, then from which class
>   does it inherit: B, or C?

Answer (score 1):

Because, it was hard to use it. Instead, Java has `interface` what is much better solutions.