# Why does Java not support multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Yeah the title pretty much describes the question.

Are there any advantages to non allowing multiple inheritance in a programming language?

Comment: Because this is how it was designed. :)

Comment: One potential problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: Checkout this article: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/why-multiple-inheritances-are-not.html

Comment: [Why there is no multiple inheritance in Java, but implementing multiple interfaces is allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2515477/1391249)

Answer (score 1):

It removes the possibility of the so called "diamond problem" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) that can occur when a class inherits from two classes having different implementations of methods of the same name.

Java instead have interfaces. A class can implement any number of interfaces and you can use a reference of the interface type to refer to any object of a class that implements this interface. Interfaces does not contain implementations and cannot be instantiated.