# any way to extend Activity if something else is already been extended?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, custom-adapter

Making a custom spinner and I want to asynchronously retrieve images and json from the web. I found a library to help with that, loopj, and it works perfectly, however when I try to put it in my Adapter class, it doesn't like "findViewById" since I am not extending Activity, but I am already extending ArrayAdapter. Is there any way to extend both? I don't fully understand extend, so I apologize if that's a stupid question, but how can I solve my problem? Instead of hardcoding images in I would much rather be able to import them from web.

My problem is at the "SmartViewImage image = ..." code. I am not sure how to solve this issue and still be able to asynchronously do what I want. I will also want to retrieve text so I am kind of stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    public Resources res;
    SpinnerModel tempValues=null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;



    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(
                          MainActivity activitySpinner, 
                          int textViewResourceId,   
                          ArrayList objects,
                          Resources resLocal
                         ) 
     {
        super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);
        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = activitySpinner;
        data     = objects;
        res      = resLocal;


        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


      }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);

        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (SpinnerModel) data.get(position);

        TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.course);
        TextView sub          = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        ImageView companyLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) 
                findViewById(R.id.my_image);

        if(position==0){

            // Default selected Spinner item 
            label.setText("Please select course");
            sub.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            // Set values for spinner each row 
            label.setText(tempValues.getCourseName());
            sub.setText(tempValues.getCourseShortDesc());
            companyLogo.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.androidexample.customspinner:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null)); //line that gets image//////


            image.setImageUrl("http://iam.colum.edu/students/jordan.max/poker.png");

        }   

        return row;
      }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) 
                activity.findViewById(R.id.my_image);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. So you cannot make your CustomAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter and Activity. There is an interesting [discussion about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515477/why-there-is-no-multiple-inheritance-in-java-but-implementing-multiple-interfac) So you need to find another way of doing that

Answer (score 3):

You already have `activity` field in your adapter, use this:

```
SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) 
                activity.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

but, as I see you dont set `activity` to anything, you can (I suppose) use `activity = activitySpinner;` in your constructor.

Also, if your CustomAdapter is internal to MainActivity, then you can simply use `MainActivity.this`.

Java does not support multiple inheritance, so you cannot extend from two classes.