# Can an interface method have a body?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-implementation

I know that an interface is like a 100% pure abstract class. So, it can't have method implementation in it. But, I saw a strange code. Can anyone explain it?

**Code Snippet:**

```
 interface Whoa {
        public static void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("This is not default implementation");
        }
 }
```

**EDIT:**

My IDE is Intellij Idea 13.1. The project SDK is java 7 <1.7.0_25>. The IDE is not showing any compiler error. But, When I compile the code at command line I am getting the following message.

> ```
> Whoa.java:2: error: modifier static not allowed here
>     public static void doStuff() {
>                        ^
> ```

Comment: it is giving error. Jdk 1.6

Comment: Thats impossible in Java

Comment: Nope. Use an abstract class instead.

Comment: Java8 allows default method body for interfaces.

Comment: Idea IDE doesn't complain about it?

Comment: Java 8, yes.  Before that, no.

Comment: above code with not compile.

Comment: Only in Java 8 default methods have been introduced. Before that No.

Comment: @The-Guy-With-The-Hat: the OS is irrelevant. Unless you meant to say 'version of Java'

Comment: Tagged *[tag:java8] , [tag:default-implementation]*

Comment: @The-Guy-With-The-Hat: ah. My mistake. You're reminding me why I prefer Python :)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The JRE which the IDE runs on is completely separate from the JDK which is used for applications.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat But still, the IDE might run in Java 6 yet you can choose to compile and run your application in Java 7 or 8 or whatever you have installed. It's completely separate.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Oh, okay. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

From **Java 8** you can define static methods in interfaces in addition to default methods.

- A static method is a method that is associated with the class in which it is defined rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares its static methods.
- This makes it easier for you to organize helper methods in your libraries; you can keep static methods specific to an interface in the same interface rather than in a separate class.
- The following example defines a static method that retrieves a `ZoneId` object corresponding to a time zone identifier; it uses the system default time zone if there is no `ZoneId` object corresponding to the given identifier. (As a result, you can simplify the method `getZonedDateTime`)

Here is code :

```
public interface TimeClient {
   // ...
    static public ZoneId getZoneId (String zoneString) {
        try {
            return ZoneId.of(zoneString);
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid time zone: " + zoneString +"; using default time zone instead.");
            return ZoneId.systemDefault();
        }
    }

   default public ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime(String zoneString) {
      return ZonedDateTime.of(getLocalDateTime(), getZoneId(zoneString));
   }    
}
```

### See also

- [Oracle docs for interface methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)
- For all interesting things in Java 8 read [Everything about Java 8](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/)

Comment: Also default implementations of methods.

Comment: I am not using java 8. It is javac 1.7.0_25.

Comment: Is your IDE using code compliance 8? That should __not__ compile with 7 and below. Here's a [good article](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/).

Comment: As per the article, check the new methods added to the [`Comparator` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in Java 8.

Comment: @Phoenix I am also using 1.7.0_25 version but it is not allowed in this version

Comment: Idea is configured to 1.7.0_25. But still it doesn't show compiler error. But at command line I am getting error.

Comment: This seems to really blur the lines between interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: @JeffGohlke See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591499/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-classes-and-interfaces-in-java-8

Comment: "Everything about java 8" link has been changed or you have posted the wrong URL which will be a rare case.  "Updated on "https://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/27/everything-about-java-8/" 27th instead of 26th march

Answer (score 21):

This is only possible in Java 8. In the [Java **7** Language Specification §9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4), it explicitly states:

> It is a compile-time error if a method declared in an interface is declared static, because static methods cannot be abstract.

So in Java 7, static methods in interfaces *cannot* exist.

If you go to the [Java **8** Language Specification §9.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3), you can see that it says:

> A static method also has a block body, which provides the implementation of the method.

So it explicitly states that in Java 8, they *can* exist.

I even tried to run your exact code in Java 1.7.0_45, but it gave me the error "modifier static not allowed here".

---

Here is a quote directly from the Java ***8*** tutorial, [Default Methods (Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html#static):

> ### Static Methods
>
> In addition to default methods, you can define [static methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in
>   interfaces. (A static method is a method that is associated with the
>   class in which it is defined rather than with any object. Every
>   instance of the class shares its static methods.) This makes it easier
>   for you to organize helper methods in your libraries; you can keep
>   static methods specific to an interface in the same interface rather
>   than in a separate class. The following example defines a static
>   method that retrieves a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object corresponding to a time
>   zone identifier; it uses the system default time zone if there is no
>   `ZoneId` object corresponding to the given identifier. (As a result,
>   you can simplify the method `getZonedDateTime`):
>
> ```
> public interface TimeClient {
>     // ...
>     static public ZoneId getZoneId (String zoneString) {
>         try {
>             return ZoneId.of(zoneString);
>         } catch (DateTimeException e) {
>             System.err.println("Invalid time zone: " + zoneString +
>                 "; using default time zone instead.");
>             return ZoneId.systemDefault();
>         }
>     }
>
>     default public ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime(String zoneString) {
>         return ZonedDateTime.of(getLocalDateTime(), getZoneId(zoneString));
>     }    
> }
> ```
>
> Like static methods in classes, you specify that a method definition
>   in an interface is a static method with the `static` keyword at the
>   beginning of the method signature. All method declarations in an
>   interface, including static methods, are implicitly `public`, so you
>   can omit the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 17):

For **java** version **7 or below**, similar functionally you can achieve using nested class declared within interface body. and this nested class implements outer interface.

### Example:

```
interface I1{
    public void doSmth();

    class DefaultRealizationClass implements  I1{

        @Override
        public void doSmth() {
           System.out.println("default realization");
        }
    }
}
```

### How do we use it in our code?

```
class MyClass implements I1{

    @Override
    public void doSmth() {
         new I1.DefaultRealizationClass().doSmth();
    }   
}
```

Therefore default implementation encapsulated within interface.

Answer (score 2):

Over the period java interfaces have evolved a lot and Java 8 completely changed the way interfaces were presumed.

Coming to question, yes we can have a method body in the interface.

whereas in **java 8** we can have a method body in a **static method** and in the **default method** like the below example.

```
interface CheckMyEvolution{   
 default void whatsNew() {   
     System.out.print("Hello there!Check my Evolution");   
 } 

static ZoneId getZoneId (String zoneString) {
    try {
        return ZoneId.of(zoneString);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.err.println("Invalid time zone: " + zoneString +
            "; using default time zone instead.");
        return ZoneId.systemDefault();
    }
}
}
```

we can also have the **private method** in the interfaces from java 9 onwards. like below code compiles well in **java 9** and above versions but fails in java 8 and below

```
interface CheckMyEvolution{   
     default void whatsNew() {   
         checkIt();   
     }   
     // Private method  
     private void checkIt() {   
         System.out.println("Hello there! I can have private method now. Make sure you are using JDK 9 or Above.");   
     }   
 }   
    public class CheckMyEvolutionImpl implements CheckMyEvolution{   
     public static void main(String[] args) {   
         CheckMyEvolution evolution= new CheckMyEvolutionImpl();   
         evolution.whatsNew();   
     } 
}
```

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html
[https://www.quora.com/profile/Rajat-Singh-187/Private-Method-in-the-Java-Interface]