# Why is the diamond case with its common ancestor used to explain Java multiple inheritance issue, instead of two unrelated parent classes?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

This question might sound weird to Java people but if you try to explain this, it would be great.

In these days I am clearing some of Java's very basic concept. 
So I come to Inheritance and Interface topic of Java.

While reading this I found that Java does not support Multiple Inheritance and also understood that, what I am not able to understand that why everywhere Diamond figure issue(At least 4 class to create diamond) is discussed to explain this behavior, Can't we understand this issue using 3 classes only.

Say, I have class A and class B, these two classes are different (they are not child class of common class) but they have one common method and they look like :-

```
class A {
    void add(int a, int b) {

    }
}

class B {
    void add(int a, int b) {

    }
}
```

Ok,Now say if Java supports Multiple inheritance and if there is one class which is the subclass of A and B like this :-

```
class C extends A,B{ //If this was possible
    @Override
    void add(int a, int b) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.add(a, b); //Which version of this, from A or B ?
    }
 }
```

then compiler will not be able to find which method to call whether from A or B and that is why Java does not support Multiple Inheritance. So is there any thing wrong with this concept ?

When I read about this topic I was able to understand Diamond issue, but I am not able to understand why people are not giving example with three class (If this is valid one, because we used only 3 classes to demonstrate issue so its easy to understand by comparing it to Diamond issue.)

Let me know whether this example does not fit to explain issue or this can also be  referred to understand issue.

**Edit:**
I got one close vote here stating that question is not clear. 
Here is main question :-

Can I understand Why "Java does not support Multiple Inheritance" with 3 classes only as described above or I must need to have 4 classes (Diamond structure) to understand the issue.

Comment: Please *cite* a place where four classes are used to support the case against diamond inheritance. At the moment your question is based on unsupported assertion.

Comment: @EJP The diamond figure has four vertices, corresponding to four classes. Why would a citation be needed to support this basic truth?

Comment: @MarkoTopolink Because he claims that it is stated 'everywhere" without a single citation. Do you have one?

Comment: @EJP You bet I have. They are very easy to come by.

Comment: @EJP By saying everywhere I mean wherever and whenever I search for reason "Why Java does not supports Multiple Inheritance" I come with with example which is based on four class.(Diamond). Please don't catch that word only. 

Well its very easy to find number of tutorials which is stating this but here is one just for reference :-
http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/

Comment: I would make this question language agnostic, as it is not a strictly Java question, but applies to several languages.

Comment: I have always wondered this myself.  It seems like a very complex example when your 3 class version is sufficient to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591499/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-classes-and-interfaces-in-java-8

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem with diamond inheritance is not so much [**shared behaviour** but **shared state**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html). As you can see, Java in fact has always supported multiple inheritance, but only **multiple inheritance of type**.

With only three classes the problem is resolved relatively easily by introducing a simple construct like `super.A` or `super.B`. And while you're only looking at overridden methods, it indeed doesn't matter whether you have a common ancestor or just the basic three classes.

However if `A` and `B` have a common ancestor, the state of which they both inherit, then you're in serious trouble. Do you store two separate copies of the state of this common ancestor? That would be more like composition than inheritance. Or do you only store one that is shared by both `A` and `B`, causing strange interactions when they manipulate their inherited shared state?

```
class A {
  protected int foo;
}

class B extends A {
  public B() {
    this.foo = 42;
  }
}

class C extends A {
  public C() {
    this.foo = 0xf00;
  }
}

class D extends B,C {
  public D() {
    System.out.println( "Foo is: "+foo ); //Now what?
  }
}
```

Note how the above wouldn't be so big a problem if class `A` didn't exist and both `B` and `C` declared their own `foo` field. There would still be a problem of clashing names, but that could be resolved with some namespacing construct (`B.this.foo` and `C.this.foo` maybe, as we do with inner classes?). The true diamond problem on the other hand is more than a naming clash, it's a matter of how to maintain class invariants when two unrelated superclasses of `D` (`B` and `C`) share the same state they both inherit from `A`. This is why all four classes are needed to demonstrate the full extent of the problem.

Shared behaviour in multiple inheritance doesn't exhibit the same problem. So much so that the recently introduced [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) do exactly that. This means that multiple inheritance of implementations is allowed now too. There is still some complication around the resolution of which implementation to call but since interfaces are stateless, the biggest bugbear is avoided.

Comment: So Java was designed into a corner that made multiple inheritance impossible?

Comment: @Svante You can put it that way, but you'd probably be looking at it the wrong way around. Multiple inheritance (of state) isn't a goal. It's a tool that you either want to use or not. What they said is "there's very little to gain from multiple inheritance of state but it will cause a lot of problems". On the other hand, multiple inheritance of types is good, we want that. So a compromise has been struck where you get most of the benefits of multiple inheritance with none of the baggage that comes with multiple inheritance of state.

Comment: This example makes more sense as its well maintained and more managed however I still don't have answer, point here is that Java will unable to decide which method to call if more than one same method with same signature (overriding) of different superclass is present at a time, and thats what I am also doing with above three classes so is this valid example ? or I must have one common superclass which is the base class of all classes used to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @RoshanJha Your three-class scenario is a valid example that demonstrates **one of the problems** that arise from multiple inheritance. But it doesn't cover all the problems and it isn't a diamond.

Comment: Your example and @kapep's explanation tells that how Diamond figure fits very well to explain issue.When we talk about Inheritance then classes should relate to each other somehow (parent-child), and diamond figure shows this while triangle figure does not fit into it very well(because of two different parent class which never interact with each other).But point here is that Java face issue to call correct version of method in such cases and triangle also shows this case so we can use triangle example as well.This seems more easier and quick understanding figure to some people (like me :)).

Comment: Thanks all for your efforts and time.

Comment: "Now what" is very simple: define an ordering of the constructor invocation.  It's just graph traversal.

Comment: @Svante It isn't simple because whatever order you choose, you've broken the invariants of either `B` or `C`. Or you duplicated the state of `A` to preserve invariants, but broke the Liskov substitution principle, in that `D` isn't in an `is a` relationship with `A` but rather in an `is two` relationship. Anyway, the point isn't that the problem can't be resolved, of course it can. The point is to highlight why this problem only arises when you have 4 classes and not when you have 3.

Comment: @Roshan Jha: the three-class example doesn’t convince because today with Java 8 we *can* create such a problem as interfaces can have implementation (aka `default`) methods. The simple answer is: the compiler will give you an error if you don’t override ambiguous inherited methods in the implementation class. However, in the case of inherited *state* there is no way to override and fix the problem.

Comment: @biziclop: if the invariants of `B` and `C` are incompatible, then inheriting from both is simply a mistake.  Duplicating the state that is defined in `A` does not make sense.  What is really getting on my nerves is stopping at "now what" like it is an insurmountable problem, but I realize that the question actually is much narrower than that.

Comment: @Svante There's no implication whatsoever that the problem is insurmountable. It has been resolved in various ways in many other languages. But to reiterate: the question was "why do we need 4 classes for the diamond problem?" and the example is merely a demonstration of how to produce a problem that only ever occurs with 4 classes and not with 3.

Answer (score 11):

Java does not support multiple inheritance because the designers of the language designed Java this way. Other languages like C++ support multiple inheritance just fine, so it is not a technical issue but just a design criteria.

The problem with multiple inheritance is that it is not always clear which method from which class you are calling to, and which instance variables you are accessing to. Different people interpret it differently and the Java designers believed at that time that it was better to skip multiple inheritance altogether.

C++ solves the diamond shaped class issue with *[virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)*:

> Virtual inheritance is a technique used in object-oriented
>   programming, where a particular base class in an inheritance hierarchy
>   is declared to share its member data instances with any other
>   inclusions of that same base in further derived classes. For example,
>   if class A is normally (non-virtually) derived from class X (assumed
>   to contain data members), and class B likewise, and class C inherits
>   from both classes A and B, it will contain two sets of the data
>   members associated with class X (accessible independently, often with
>   suitable disambiguating qualifiers). But if class A is virtually
>   derived from class X instead, then objects of class C will contain
>   only one set of the data members from class X. The best-known language
>   that implements this feature is C++.

Contrary to Java, in C++ you can disambiguate which instance method to call by prefixing the call with the name of the class:

```
class X {
  public: virtual void f() { 

  } 
};

class Y : public X {
  public: virtual void f() { 

  } 
};

class Z : public Y {
  public: virtual void f() { 
    X::f();
  } 
};
```

Comment: Actualy Java does support multiple inheritance. At least kind of. Before Java 8 it was possible to define Constants on interfaces. Since Java 8 it is possible to define methods on interfaces (default methods). In case of ambiguities you have to use the interface name explicitly.

Comment: I don't know it that's what you meant but implementing two interfaces is not multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ArthurRizzo It is, it's just a different one. There is multiple inheritance of type, of behaviour and of state. Multiple inheritance of type is supported by Java via interfaces. Multiple inheritance of behaviour is supported by default methods (which basically makes them traits), and multiple inheritance of state isn't supported and is unlikely to be in the foreseeable future.

Comment: At least that is the terminology used in Java documentation, that's what @dusky is referring to.

Answer (score 7):

That is just one difficulty that you have to solve for multiple inheritance in a language.  Since there exist languages that do have multiple inhertance (e.g. Common Lisp, C++, Eiffel), it is obviously not insurmountable.

Common Lisp defines the exact strategy for priorizing (ordering) the inheritance graph, so there is no ambiguity in the rare cases where it does matter in practice.

C++ uses virtual inheritance (I have not yet put the effort in to understand what that means).

Eiffel allows to specify exactly how you want to inherit, possibly renaming methods in the subclass.

Java just skipped multiple inheritance.  (I personally think that it is difficult not to be  insulting to its designers while trying to rationalize this decision.  Of course, it is hard to think about a thing when the language you think *in* does not support it.)

Answer (score 6):

The diamond problem with four classes is simpler than three classes problem described in the question.

The problem with three classes adds another issue that has to be solved first: The naming conflict caused by two unrelated `add` methods with the same signature. It's not actually hard to solve but it adds unnecessary complexity. It would probably be allowed in Java (like it is already allowed to implement multiple unrelated interface methods with the same signature), but there could be languages that simply prohibit multiple inheritance of similar methods without a common ancestor.

By adding a fourth class which defines `add`, it is clear that both `A` and `B` are implementing the *same* `add` method.

So the diamond problem is more clear because it shows the problem using simple inheritance instead of just using methods with the same signature. It is well known and probably applies to a wider range of programming languages, so the variation of it with three classes (which adds the additional naming conflict issue) doesn't make much sense and therefore hasn't been adopted.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by additional naming conflict issue.

However I got your point that instead of using two different classes which don't interact any how with each other, its good to create kind of family classes.

But point here is that Java will unable to decide which method to call if more than one same method with same signature (overriding) of different superclass is present at a time, so Is 3 class example is valid example or not ?

Comment: The "conflict" is that the two methods are unrelated but coincidentally share the same signature - and there are multiple ways the language _could_ handle this. It is easy to solve with a specification that either allows or disallows that two methods with the same signature but no common base can exist in a class. But there is no such specification in java. If we assume it is allowed (which granted would be very likely), then I think the 3 class example could be used instead of the diamond. The diamond is more general though and  doesn't need any assumption about how to handle the conflict.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple inheritance is no problem if you find a sane solution to method resolution. When you invoke a method on an object, method resolution is the act of picking which class'es version of the method should be used. For this, the inheritance graph is linearized. Then, the first class in this sequence that provides an implementation of the requested method is chosen.

To illustrate the following examples of conflict resolution strategies, we will be using this diamond inheritance graph:

```
    +-----+
    |  A  |
    |=====|
    |foo()|
    +-----+
       ^
       |
   +---+---+
   |       |
+-----+ +-----+
|  B  | |  C  |
|=====| |=====|
|foo()| |foo()|
+-----+ +-----+
   ^       ^
   |       |
   +---+---+
       |
    +-----+
    |  D  |
    |=====|
    +-----+
```

- The most flexible strategy is requiring the programmer to **explicitly choose** the implementation when creating an ambiguous class, by explicitly overriding the conflicting method. A variant of this is banning multiple inheritance. If a programmer wants to inherit behaviour from multiple classes, composition will have to be used, and a number of proxy methods to be written. However, naively explicitly resolved inheritance conflicts has the same shortcomings as…
- **Depth first search**, which might create the linearization `D, B, A, C`. But this way, `A::foo()` is considered before `C::foo()` although `C::foo()` *overrides* `A::foo()`! This can't be what we wanted. An example of a language using DFS is Perl.
- Use a **clever algorithm** that guarantees that if `X` is a subclass of `Y`, it will always come before `Y` in the linearization. Such an algorithm will not be able to unravel all inheritance graphs, but it provides sane semantics in most cases: If a class overrides a method, it will always be preferred over the overridden method. This algorithm exists and is called **[C3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)**. This would create the linearization `D, B, C, A`. C3 was first presented in 1996. Unfortunately, Java was published in 1995 – so C3 was not known when Java was initially designed.
- **Use composition, not inheritance – revisited.** Some solutions to multiple inheritance suggest getting rid of the “class inheritance” bit, and instead propose other units of composition. One example is **mixins**, which “copy & paste” method definitions into your class. This is incredibly crude.

  The idea of mixins has been refined into **[traits](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/traits/)** (presented 2002, also too late for Java). Traits are a more general case of both classes and interfaces. When you “inherit” a trait, the definitions are embedded into your class, so that this does not complicate method resolution. Unlike mixins, traits provide more nuanced strategies to resolve conflicts. Especially, the order in which traits are composed matters. Traits play a prominent role in Perl's “Moose” object system (called [roles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Roles)) and in [Scala](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/traits.html).

Java prefers single inheritance for another reason: If each class can only have one superclass, we don't have to apply complicated method resolution algorithms – the inheritance chain already is the method resolution order. This makes methods a bit more efficient.

Java 8 introduced default methods which look similar to traits. However, the rules of Java's method resolution make interfaces with default methods much less capable than traits. Still, a step in the direction of adapting modern solutions to the multiple-inheritance problem.

In most multiple inheritance method resolution schemes, the order of superclasses does matter. That is, there's a difference between `class D extends B, C` and `class D extends C, B`. Because the order can be used for simple disambiguation, a three-class example does not sufficiently demonstrate the problems associated with multiple inheritance. You need a full four-class diamond problem for that, as it shows how naive depth-first search leads to an unintuitive method resolution order.

Comment: Choosing the right methods from the set of applicable methods is solved in Common Lisp, too, which was standardized in 1994 (but drafts were available much earlier).

Comment: @Svante Yes, Common Lisp has an awesome object system that was and in some respects still is “leading the pack” (some features like the meta-object protocol and method combinators are slowly seeping into more mainstream languages). CL has a very intuitive linearization, and is referenced and compared to in the C3 linearization paper (“A Monotonic Superclass Linearization for Dylan”). Unfortunately that paper is behind a paywall, so I'm not sure what specific problems with CL's class precedence algorithm were fixed by C3.

Answer (score 0):

The diamond problem that you cite is one reason (and a very good one) not to support multiple inheritance.  There are other reasons too, which you can [read a bit about here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/why-multiple-inheritances-are-not.html).

A lot of the reasons boil down to complexity (it's quite complex to do it right), the relatively rare legitimate need to use it, and all sorts of other problems with dispatching (aside from just the diamond problem) that it creates.

Comment: I recommend the book "Design Patterns and Contracts", where the GoF Design Patterns are explored in Eiffel, which does allow multiple inheritance.  The authors use multiple inheritance quite naturally in several cases.  It is just hard to think about cubes when your mind is flat.

Comment: Yes, thats is what I want to ask here, Can we use this example to understand why "Java does not support multiple inheritance" or this example fails somewhere which I am not able to see ?

Comment: @RoshanJha I'm afraid that diamond problem is not the answer. It is a problem, but for methods it can be solved trivially (enforced disambiguation). For state, just forbid inheriting a stateful class twice. With these rules I see no more problems...

Comment: @RoshanJha Which "this" one you mean? You started with a triangle, and it has a problem of its own. As Marko Topolnik shows, in a diamond it gets a bit worse. So far everything can be solved by enforcing disambiguation. And there's no big difference between the triangle and the diamond. Now let's add some state. No new problem with the triangle, but the diamonds leads to big headaches. Should the double inherited state exist once or twice? How do the methods find it in an object (so far there was a fixed offset; this doesn't work anymore)?