# Java: Mixin implementation classes

Tags: java, mixins

I've seen in several code libraries classes named **Mixin** with comments like:

```
//Mixin style implementation
public class DetachableMixin implements Detachable {}
```

Which is the concept under this style of implementations?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a qoute from Joshua Bloch "Efective Java" (I don't think, I could explain it better myself):

> Interfaces are ideal for defining mixins. Loosely speaking, a mixin is a type
>   that a class can implement in addition to its “primary type” to declare that it provides
>   some optional behavior. For example, Comparable is a mixin interface that
>   allows a class to declare that its instances are ordered with respect to other mutually
>   comparable objects. Such an interface is called a mixin because it allows the
>   optional functionality to be “mixed in” to the type’s primary functionality.
>   Abstract classes can’t be used to define mixins for the same reason that they can’t
>   be retrofitted onto existing classes: a class cannot have more than one parent, and
>   there is no reasonable place in the class hierarchy to insert a mixin.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is spot on, but it might be worth pointing out that other JVM languages go even further.

Scala for examples has [traits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html) - basically "interfaces" with method implementations. In scala, you can *mix* one class together with multiple traits, thereby allowing to inherit **behavior** from several different "places.

Basically the same concept that Java picked up with Java 8, where you know can add *default* method behavior to interfaces. And for the record: if I recall it correctly, Java8 interfaces and default methods are **not** meant to introduce a full "mixin" concept in the Java language. The idea is **not** that you should use this feature to achieve multiple inheritance through the back door. See this lengthy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997052/reason-for-adding-default-and-static-methods-in-interfaces/30000456#30000456) from Stuart Mark, one of the people driving the Java language evolution. They state:

> The purpose of default methods ... is to enable interfaces to be evolved in a compatible manner after their initial publication.

Answer (score 0):

A good article about implementing `mixin` pattern with `Virtual Extension Methods` since Java 8: https://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/java-8-now-you-have-mixins/

> The virtual extension method is something new in Java. It brings another mean of expression to create new patterns and best pratices. This article provides an example of such a pattern, enabled in Java 8 due to the use of virtual extension methods. I am sure you can extract other new patterns from them. But, as I have experienced here, you should not hesitate to share them in a view to check their validaty.